# Replication of a normally distributed variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, normal-distribution, sampling, sample

Suppose we know there is a **True Effect size = + 0.2** for an experiment. Now, suppose that I want to find out what happens if I repeat the exact same experiment **10,000 times**. **If I believe such repetitions will create a *normal distribution of effect sizes*** **with some standard error**, **is the following the correct way to describe the sampling distribution of these 10,000 repeatedly obtained effect sizes? (If yes, *why True effect size only + and not - the right-hand side terms*)**

```
True Effect Size + Standard Error * rnorm(10000)  ## `rnorm()` is R code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. You do not need a minus sign because the noise term (generated by `rnorm`) is symmetric about zero, and produces both positive and negative values.